# Multiple parameter grid search in R to maximize correlation of two time series

Tags: r, matrix, multidimensional-array, correlation, r-grid

I would like to maximize the following correlation:

```
corr(qhat, [0, mu_2, mu_3, mu_4]*inv(I - mu_1*A)*D),
```

where qhat is a time series of length 90; `mu_1,`mu_2`,`mu_3`, and`mu_4`are essentially the parameters I would like to run the grid search over;`I`is the 4 X 4 identity matrix;`A`is a 4 X 4 matrix of coefficients; here`inv`represents the matrix inverse operator;`D` is a matrix of dimension 4 X 90 (a time series of 4 variables). I searched and found a similar problem and tried to hack the solution to fit my needs. I tried the following in R (apologies for the redundant code, I wanted to break everything up so what I am attempting is clear):

```
#Define the parameter space 
param_space = expand.grid(
  mu_1 = seq(0, 1, length.out = 11),
  mu_2 = seq(0, 1, length.out = 11),
  mu_3 = seq(0, 1, length.out = 11), 
  mu_4 = seq(0, 1, length.out = 11))

e = as.vector(param_space$mu_1)
f = as.vector(param_space$mu_2)
g = as.vector(param_space$mu_3)
h = as.vector(param_space$mu_4)
P = matrix(c(e,f,g,h),ncol=4)

J = diag(4)
J[1,1]=0
Q = P%*%J

target.val = cor(as.vector(qhat), Q%*%solve(I - param_space$mu_1*A)%*%t(varset))
solution = which.max(target.val)
param_space[solution,]
```

The object `param_space` ends up with dimension 14641 X 4. I used the `as.vector` functions above to avoid the errors which pop up in R with regards to using non-numeric objects to perform matrix operations on. D in the generalized equation above has been replaced with `t(varset)` here in the actual code. Dimension of the object `t(varset)` is 4 X 90.

Here is a piece of information which may/may not be useful: When I simply copy and paste

```
 Q%*%solve(I - param_space$mu_1*A)%*%t(varset)
```

into my console, I get the same error as when I run the code I wrote above. Namely,

```
"Error in solve(I - param_space$mu_1 * A) : 
  dims [product 16] do not match the length of object [14641]
```

In addition: Warning message:

```
In param_space$mu_1 * A :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"
```

so I am thinking I have set up the grid search inappropriately. Any help would be appreciated. This is actually my first post, so I appreciate this resource, as well. Not to be picky, but I am trying to avoid looping in R.

-Chris